# Run PHP when a variable changes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli

I have an issue with my php code. I want to add something into my database when a variable changes. I'm getting a variable from another file that changes.

below you can find the code:

```
$urlMachineON = 'http://192.168.0.150/awp/Shredder/PLCfiles/IOmachineActive.html';

// get content
$contentMachineON = file_get_contents($urlMachineON);

//remove first 2 characters
$truncate = substr($contentMachineON, 2);

//remove last 5 characters
$MachineOn = substr($truncate, 0, -5);

if ($MachineOn == 0)
{
    echo "de machine staat uit";
    //Send information to the database
    //example: current time + MachineStatus(off) + message(Machine offline Error X)
}
elseif($MachineOn == 1)
{
    echo "de machine staat aan";
    //Send information to the database
    //example: current time + MachineStatus(on) + message(Error X is solved)
}
```

When I do it like this it will only set information in my database when I refresh my webpage or use some kind of button. But it kinda has to go automatic. So when the variable `$MachineOn` goes from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0 it has to add information in my database. How can I solve this?

Comment: Use a task scheduler like cron on Linux to run your script periodically.

Comment: As @jeroen said, you want to run a cronjob or a windows scheduled task depending on your hosting to achieve this. **Do not hide this in a file regularly accessed by users**. This might seem to achieve your goal but I've seen similar bad decisions really degrade site performance.

Comment: And how can I do this? Never heard anything about this before.

Comment: I've found something about cronjobs but it shows only time related stuff (like every friday). Thats not my thing. My variable changes not on a exact time....

Answer (score 0):

if this changes during the same execution, you can use

```
static $previousMachineOn=$MachineOn;
if($previousMachineOn!=$MachineOn){
//changed
$previousMachineOn=$MachineOn;
//handle the change
}
```

if this changes during the same session, you can use

```
$_SESSION['previousMachineOn']=(array_key_exists('previousMachineOn',$_SESSION)?$_SESSION['previousMachineOn']:$MachineOn);
if($_SESSION['previousMachineOn']!=$MachineOn){
//changed
$_SESSION['previousMachineOn']=$MachineOn
//handle the change
}
```

if it neither change during execution, nor during the session,

```
if(file_get_contents("previousMachineOn.txt")!=$MachineOn)
{
//changed
file_put_contents("previousMachineOn.txt",$MachineOn,LOCK_EX);
//handle the change
}
```

or maybe you can use a database, or a simple text file, telling when last it was updated, and re-update if it was too long ago

```
if(file_get_contents("lastupdatetime.txt")-time()>1*60*60)
{
//more than 1 hour since last update.
//update lastupdatetime
file_put_contents("lastupdatetime.txt",time(),LOCK_EX);
//update code goes here
}
```

or perhaps you could have a local cached copy, and a cronjob to update it routinely.. in which case, you'll probably want some way to deal with the race condition of the cronjob deleting the file for promptly replacing it with the updated version (file_put_contents with LOCK_EX should do the trick, i believe, but be aware that in my experience, LOCK_EX is dodgy/nonfunctional on Windows* XP/7 OSs)